# Is it safe to use a 100W powerbank in a laptop that needs 65W only?

Tags: power-bank

I bought a 65W powerbank that worked well with my laptop that uses a **65W** charger.

However, when the powerbank reaches 50%, it starts producing  less than **65W**.

That's why I was thinking of using a powerbank with more than 65W (for instance, **100W**).

Is it a safe bet?

Answer (score 2):

Mostly yes

When charging a laptop, the powerbank will push a specific voltage, and the laptop will pull a specific amount of current. In the case of USB-C, they will then contact each other to get the optimal amount of voltage and current, and will run that. If you charge your laptop over USB-C, this will be safe, if not, check first if the voltages are within like 0.05V of each other.